# -moz-transform and scale. Cross-browser solution

Tags: css

I'm using this css styling :

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
   -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

And it works in FF. Unfortunatelly, I do not know how to do the same thing in other popular browsers (at least, Opera, Chrome and IE).

Comment: Take it easy, guys :)

Answer (score 2):

The various prefixes you might need.

```
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
   transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Supplied by [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) as accessed in [**Codepen.io**](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: And don't you know how to force vertical scrolling on a page? The problem is, when I soom the page, I see no scroll bar and it is not convinient.

Comment: Transforms are *visual* changes only...you're not actually changing the size of the element. It's not clear what you are trying to do. I would suggest that you ask **another separate** question with the specifics of your actual requirement. Please don't change *this* question as it may invalidte the answers you have already received.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `-moz` prefix

```
  transform: scale(1.5); /* it works in all modern browsers */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* it works for iOS and older Chrome*/
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* it works in IE < 11 */
```